# What service should a Prosody mod_proxy65 proxy offer?

Tags: proxy, xmpp, prosody

I am adding the [mod_proxy65](https://prosody.im/doc/modules/mod_proxy65) module to a Prosody server so that it is suitable for XMPP clients supporting [XEP-0065](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html). This allows file transfers between clients that are each behind a firewall (NAT).

Minimal configuration examples:

```
Component "proxy.example.com" "proxy65"
```

or

```
Component "proxy.example.com" "proxy65"
    proxy65_address = "example.com"
    proxy65_acl = { "example.com" }
```

The documentation (linked above) suggests that the mod_proxy65 component should point to "a bytestream proxy", but what does this mean, concretely? What is an example of a service I should install at the `proxy.example.com` endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Prosody users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prosody-users/jLFfKhDjMnA), `mod_proxy65` is itself the "bytestream proxy" service, and `proxy.example.com` is just a different DNS record pointing to the same Prosody server.

If you don't want to set up an additional DNS record, use `proxy65_address` to direct the client to the existing DNS record of your Prosody server.

See the mailing list message (above) and ["File and image transfer" in *Extra Modules for Prosody*](https://samhobbs.co.uk/2016/09/extra-modules-prosody-instant-message-chat-server-raspberry-pi-ubuntu) for more details.